# How to change opacity on MaterialCard clicked?

Tags: xaml, mvvm, xamarin.forms, opacity

In my HomePage.xaml I have material:MaterialCard.

```
<material:MaterialCard Grid.Column="0"
                       BackgroundColor="{StaticResource CustomizedRedColor}"
                       WidthRequest="70"
                       HeightRequest="70"
                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                       CornerRadius="4"
                       Elevation="1"
                       Padding="5"
                       x:Name="CreateMQRCard"
                       Opacity="{Binding Opacity}"
                       Clicked="MaterialCard_Clicked">
                <material:MaterialCard.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding CreateMQRCommand}" />
                </material:MaterialCard.GestureRecognizers>

                <Image Source="create_new_mqr.png"
                       Aspect="Fill"
                       HeightRequest="55"
                       WidthRequest="55"
                       HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
            </material:MaterialCard>
```

So I binded Opacity to property in my HomeViewModel.cs:

```
public double Opacity { get; set; } = 1;
```

Then, in `CreateMQR` method I'm trying to Change opacity just before navigating to another page.

```
private async void CreateMQR()
        {                        
            Opacity = 0.5;
            await Task.Delay(700);
            Opacity = 1;
            ShowDialog();
            await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new CreateMQRPage());
            HideDialog();
        }
```

Navigating works fine, command call method with no problem, opacity is set to values, but on screen nothing happen.
With opacity set on 0.5 and then back to 1, I want to create "blinking" effect on click. (Similar as buttons have)

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing which Control `MaterialCard` inherite from .There is an sample about image ,maybe helpful to use.

**XAML** :

```
<Image x:Name="myimage" Source="icon.png">
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

**ContentPage** :

```
private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Image image = sender as Image;
    image.Opacity = 0;
    image.FadeTo(1, 4000);
}
```

You can use **[Fading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/animation/simple#fading)** function to realize the animation when click it.